# Condition which checks, whether one is in the argument of a Latex function

Tags: latex, auctex

Auctex provides the variable `texmathp` which indicates, whether one is inside math mode. This is extremely useful, because many things in Latex-editing depend on this.

Is there a good way to check, whether one is inside the argument of a special Latex function, e.g. `\SI`, `\num`, `\qty` or `\ch`?

This would be useful, because then e.g. some snippets should only be expanded inside an argument of this function, or generally expanded, but not inside the argument of this function.

Bonus question: How can one check whether one is inside an environment?

Comment: Are you looking for the functions `TeX-current-macro` and `LaTeX-current-environment`?

Comment: Yes, those are exactly, what I was looking for. I had the feeling, that there have to be some functions in AucTex and read the manual, but I did not find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUCTeX provides two functions which should be interesting for you:

> (TeX-current-macro)
>
> Return the name of the macro containing point, nil if there is none.

and

> (LaTeX-current-environment &optional ARG)
>
> Return the name (a string) of the enclosing LaTeX environment. With
> optional ARG>=1, find that outer level.
>
> If function is called inside a comment and `LaTeX-syntactic-comments`
> is enabled, try to find the environment in commented regions with the
> same comment prefix.
>
> The functions `LaTeX-find-matching-begin` and
> `LaTeX-find-matching-end` work analogously.

Comment: Yeah, as I answered to your comment, those are exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: TeX-current-macro is not very reliable. Il fail if the macro span over several lines with comments. For instance `\includegraphics\n
[width=2cm] % comment\n
{example-image-duck}` and the point on the mage name.

Comment: @gigiair - You have to make an assumption how macros are written; `TeX-current-macro` assumes that you have the macro arguments starting on the same line as the macro itself; then they can span over several lines.  Try `\includegraphics [ \n width=2cm] {% comment \n example-image-duck \n }`

Comment: @Arash Esbati - Certainly, but the form I proposed is syntactically correct and the latex compiler accepts it without flinching. If you intend to use the `TeX-current-macro` macro, you must therefore refrain from using it.